# How do I change an object to an array in this scenario?

Tags: java, arrays, object, matrix-multiplication

I understand the issue of matrixMultiply() runs into an issue because m1 is not an array, but rather an object. There are definitely a lot more errors in the code right now, but at the moment I'm focusing on fixing this method before continuing. There is probably a simple solution, but it isn't hitting me right now.

```
public class APMatrix {

    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
    private int[][] matrix;

    public APMatrix(int R, int C, boolean enter) {

        matrix = new int[R][C];

        if (enter) {
            for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
                    matrix[r][c] = reader.readInt("What value do you want in row " + (r + 1) + ", col " + (c + 1) + "? ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public APMatrix(int[][] copyMe) {
        for (int r = 0; r < copyMe.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < copyMe[r].length; c++) {
                matrix[r][c] = copyMe[r][c];
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return matrix.length;
    }

    public int getColumns() {
        return matrix[0].length;
    }

    public APMatrix matrixMultiply(APMatrix m1) {
        if (this[0].length == m1.length) {
            int[][] m2 = new int[this.length][m1[0].length];

            for (int outer = 0; outer < this.length; outer++) {
                for (int inner = 0; inner < m1[0].length; inner++) {
                    for (int all = 0; all < m1.length; all++) {
                        m2[outer][inner] += m1[all][inner];
                    }
                }
            }
            return m2;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String retobj = "wow";
        return retobj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a getter getMatrix() that returns matrix;

Use m1.getMatrix() in matrixMultiply() instead of just m1.

Comment: What you did would work, and thank you because it got my thought process going. But instead I just referenced each method's private int[][] matrix. Thanks.

Comment: You  will also need to return new APMatrix(m2) and not just m2.